# Is that possible using snakemake to add block to every shell rule

Tags: snakemake

I am using snakemake to build workflows, I wonder that if is possible to add block to 'shell' directive of every rule when I running the workflow?

for example, I have these rules in a snakefile:

```
rule rule1:
  input:...
  output:...
  shell:"rule1command"

rule rule2:
  input:...
  output:...
  shell:"rule2command"
```

when I run the workflow, i want to add a default block when execute every shell command, for example:
I want to define a default **prefix** block: `"hostname; echo 'good luck''"`, then when execute rule1command and rule2command, it should output the hostname and echo "good luck" first.

is this possiable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I finally found the solution from the snakemake document in the [FAQ](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/faq.html?highlight=shell.prefix#i-want-to-configure-the-behavior-of-my-shell-for-all-rules-how-can-that-be-achieved-with-snakemake) part:

```
You can set a prefix that will prepended to all shell commands by adding e.g.

shell.prefix("set -o pipefail; ")
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use string concatenation:

```
prefix_block = """
    hostname
    echo 'good luck'
    """

rule rule1:
  input:...
  output:...
  shell: prefix_block + "rule1command"

rule rule2:
  input:...
  output:...
  shell: prefix_block + "rule2command"
```

Comment: Thank you Jan! This could be a solution, but it's kinda not that graceful. I must add the 'prefix_block +' to every rule, it's redundancy and not good for reading. I looking for something like a custom shell template, or 'default prefix/suffix' API of snakemake.